Proving $\lim_{n\to \infty}$ $\frac{n^2+2n+3}{n^3-2n^2-5} = 0$
I am trying to study exercises for mathematical analysis. This one, and similar ones with subtraction in the denominator have me stumped.
"Using only the definition of convergence of sequences, prove $\lim_{n\to \infty}$ $\frac{n^2+2n+3}{n^3-2n^2-5} = 0$"
Specifically trying to find similar equations that simplify the expression while still being larger. I have moved around the equation trying to find something that popped out, but the closest I get is $n^3-2n^2-5 \gt n$ when $n \geq 3$. This doesn't feel right....
$\frac{n^2+2n+3}{n^3-2n^2-5} < \frac{n^2+2n+3}{n} < \frac{n^2+5n}{n} = n+5$
Is it right? What reasoning flaw is there if it is wrong? What should I try and do you have any tips for approaching these?

Try to prove that $n^3-2n^2-5\ge \frac 12n^3$ and $n^2+2n+3\le 2n^2$ (both for $n$ large).

I am not sure I get how. Do you mean to find the n and use induction? Like n = 5 and n = 3 now apply induction to prove any bigger n will always make it hold true?

Just divide the numerator and denominator by $n^2$.

Hint - Divide the numerator and denominator by $n^3$

@QiaochuYuan In the question it says "Using only the definition of convergence"

@Cat No matter how you prove these two. You can do so by induction or directly (I did so directly). And yes, they hold for $n\ge 3$ and $n\ge 5$, respectively. So, for $n\ge 5$, you can estimate your fraction from above by $\frac 4n$.

@CroCo I get if I was just trying to calculate the limit, but because it says by the definition I assume they want proof.  When I try and find my $N$ and $\epsilon$ that's where I keep getting hung up.


Is it right?

It's "right" in the sense that it's a true statement, but it's not useful, since it doesn't prove anything about the limit.
The key here is to move everything to the highest power of $n$. In the numerator, you have $2n+3$, and if $n>3$, then this is less than $n^2$, so if you replace it with $n^2$, you get something larger.
$\frac{n^2+2n+3}{n^3-2n^2-5} < \frac{n^2+n^2}{n^3-2n^2-5}=\frac{2n^2}{n^3-2n^2-5}$
Next, you can multiply top and bottom by $2$ to get
$\frac{4n^2}{2n^3-4n^2-10}$
Now let's take $n>10$. Then $n^3 = n*n^2>10*n^2>5n^2=4n^2+n^2>4n^2+10$. Since $4n^2+10<n^3$, it follows that $-4n^2-10>-n^3$. So if we replace $-4n^2-10$ in the denominator with $-n^3$, then we're making the denominator smaller, and thus the fraction is getting bigger:
$\frac{4n^2}{2n^3-4n^2-10}<\frac{4n^2}{2n^3-n^3}=\frac{4n^2}{n^3}=\frac{4}{n}$
$
$

Thank you, I get what you are saying!

How can I make sure I keep the inequality 'useful' in the future?

@Cat In this case, it's a matter of realizing that you should be making the numerator larger and the denominator smaller, and looking for ways to do that that simplify the fraction.

Here I give an estimate from another view:
note that the coefficient of $n^2$ in $n^3-2n^2-5$ is $-2$,
so we choose $n-4$ such that
$$(n^2+2n+3)(n-4)=n^3-2n^2-5n-12.$$
Hence when $n>4$, we have
$$0<\frac{n^2+2n+3}{n^3-2n^2-5}<\frac{1}{n-4}<\epsilon.$$
So choosing $N=4+\frac1\epsilon$ will give that, when $n>N$,
$$0<\frac{n^2+2n+3}{n^3-2n^2-5}<\frac{1}{n-4}<\epsilon.$$


"Using only the definition of convergence of sequences, prove $~\displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty} ~\dfrac{n^2+2n+3}{n^3-2n^2-5} = 0$

Dividing the numerator and denominator by $~n^3~$ gives
$$f(n) = \frac{( ~1/n ~) + ( ~2/n^2 ~) + ( ~3/n^3 ~) }{1 - ( ~2/n ~) - ( ~5/n^3 ~)}. \tag1 $$
Let $~\epsilon~$ be greater than $~0.~$ 
The problem reduces to showing that there exists an $~N \in \Bbb{Z^+}~$ such that 
for all $~n \in \Bbb{Z}_{\geq N},~$ that $~| ~f(n) ~| < \epsilon.$
Choose
$$N = \max\left( ~\frac{20}{\epsilon}, ~20 ~\right) \implies \epsilon \geq \frac{20}{N}.
$$
Further, for any $~n \in \Bbb{Z}_{\geq N},~$ you have that
$$\epsilon \geq \frac{20}{n} ~~~\text{and} ~~~n \geq 20.$$
Then,
$$( ~1/n ~) + ( ~2/n^2 ~) + ( ~3/n^3 ~) < ( ~1/n ~) + ( ~2/n ~) + ( ~3/n ~) = (6/n) < \frac{\epsilon}{2}.$$
Further,
$$\frac{2}{n} + \frac{5}{n^3} \leq \frac{2}{20} + \frac{5}{20} = \frac{7}{20}.$$
Therefore,
$$1 - ( ~2/n ~) - ( ~5/n^3 ~) > \frac{1}{2}.$$
Therefore,
$$\frac{( ~1/n ~) + ( ~2/n^2 ~) + ( ~3/n^3 ~) }{1 - ( ~2/n ~) - ( ~5/n^3 ~)} < \frac{\epsilon/2}{1/2} = \epsilon.$$

Sorry need some clarification.. You chose some large N, in this case, N=20 so that the top and bottom fractions would hold true. What/where does your $\frac{2}{n} + \frac{5}{n^3}$ come from? and pretty much everything after.... I don't understand the jump from choosing an N to finding the other number for N= max.

@Cat I have that both of the following are true:  $$N \geq 20 ~~~\text{and} ~~~N \geq \frac{20}{\epsilon} \implies \epsilon \geq \frac{20}{N}.$$  The above constraints will also hold for any $~n \geq N.~$  That is, for any $~n \geq N,~$ you will have that $$n \geq 20 ~~~\text{and} ~~~n \geq \frac{20}{\epsilon} \implies \epsilon \geq \frac{20}{n}.$$  Please consider this comment and review the answer again, and then post another comment if you still have questions.

@Cat My $~\dfrac{2}{n} + \dfrac{5}{n^3}~$ comes from consideration of the denominator of $~f(n),~$ where I am trying to show that the denominator is $~> 1/2.~$  Also : "...and pretty much everything after..." isn't really helpful.  Go over the answer line by line, and ask a question on the first line that confuses you.  Then, we can proceed, line by line.

I have taken a step back and re-looked at it again line by line. I believe my confusion lies within your $\frac{20}{\epsilon}$. I understand your choice for N, I understand now what you mean for $\frac{2}{n} + \frac{5}{n^3}$ Why did you decide $\frac{6}{n} < \frac{\epsilon}{2}. What is the thought process?

@cat $$n \geq \frac{20}{\epsilon} \implies \epsilon \geq \frac{20}{n} \implies $$ $$\frac{\epsilon}{2} \geq \frac{10}{n} > \frac{1}{n} + \frac{2}{n^2} + \frac{3}{n^3}.$$
